# Add three month to a date in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL script where by I need to add three months to the existing date from the database, I have successfully done that however how do I convert the date  into a date format:
this is what I have done so far.

```
case
when be.Description = '3 Months from Purchase'
then DATEADD(Month, 3 ,ISNULL (REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11),p.CarReleasedate, 113), '', '-'),'-')) 
else '-' 
end [Expiry date]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to return '-' for the else you can't convert it to a date. What format is CarReleasedate stored as?

Comment: the CarReleasedate is store as datetime

Comment: Why all the conversions then? Why not just add 3 months to the field if it's not null?

Comment: because, in the output result not all rows has 3 months from release, so I need to check if that condition is met that I have to take the release date of the car and add 3 months to it and date the expiring date of the agreement into a column

Answer (score 2):

If it's a datetime, you can just do this:

```
DATEADD(Month, 3, CarReleasedate)
```

That returns a datetime also.

Answer (score 1):

```
case
    when be.Description = '3 Months from Purchase' AND p.CarReleasedate IS NOT NULL
    then DATEADD(Month, 3, p.CarReleasedate)
    else NULL
end [Expiry date]
```

Comment: Thanks dude but the script failed when it reaches the '-', this the message:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: How about adding the "-" in the front end when you detect a null